# Express API with SocketIO Together?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, socket.io, next.js

I have a ReactJS/Next application. I have created a separate REST API (on a different port) with Express and NodeJS. When my React app requests certain API endpoints, my API will send back responses. I also need to implement Sockets using socket.io for a component of my application for real-time. My question is do these two components -- socket.io server and the REST API -- have to be on different ports? Or even if it doesn't ***have*** to be, should it for production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A socket.io can share an http server just fine.  Socket.io puts an event handler first in the list, identifies incoming socket.io connections and grabs them, leaving everything else to go to the regular http server.  It is designed this way on purpose and works just fine.  If you don't have any compelling reasons to break them apart to put them on separate server boxes (for scaling or load management), then there is no reason to need to use separate ports for them in production.  The socket.io server can use your API's http server just fine.

FYI, socket.io uses webSocket under the covers as the core transport and the webSocket protocol was specifically designed to be able to share an http server.  In fact, all webSocket and socket.io connections start with an http request and then "upgrade" to the webSocket/socket.io protocol.

Comment: Why would it be beneficial to scaling to put it on a separate server?

Comment: @CodeRocks - That's an open ended question.  Splitting your API server into four or ten servers is beneficial to scaling, but it's pointless until you actually need to do that and have exhausted easier measures to enhance scaling first. The point is don't overdesign for something you don't yet need until you know you need it.

Comment: @CodeRocks - Nothing we're talking about here is cast in stone once you have your first implementation running.  If, after a couple years, you get to higher scale and have tweaked as many other things as you can and you decide you need to break things up to involve more physical server hardware, you do it then, not now.  And, by then, your architecture will probably have evolved some anyway.